# Recycle causes fullscreen app to un-fullscreen

Tags: windows

I use recycle.exe or nircmd moverecyclebin to delete files from the command line to the recycle bin. The problem is that if I'm using adobe flash(not sure if it causes problems with html5 players) they cause the full screen to un-fullscreen. It is quite annoying. There should be no reason why they would mess with full screen apps but they do. It seems to have to do with windows since it is happening from two different apps.

Anyway to fix this?

Ok, this does not happen with html5 so maybe only adobe flash. In html5 it does cause the "you are not in fullscreen" text to pop up again but it doesn't unfullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Both recycle,recycleIt, and nircmd moverecyclebin had the same problem I found recycle-bin.exe which works: https://github.com/sindresorhus/recycle-bin/releases/tag/v2.0.0 .